# reverse_graph argument to dijkstra_shortest_paths

Tags: boost-graph

What is the correct way to pass a `reverse_graph` as an argument to Dijkstra? I want to achieve something like this:

```
graph_t G;
vertex_descriptor u;
dijkstra_shortest_paths(G, u, 
 predecessor_map(get(vertex_predecessor,G))
  .distance_map(get(vertex_distance,G))
   .weight_map(get(edge_weight,G));
```

with the parameter that is a reverse graph adaptor:

```
reverse_graph<graph_t> R(G);
```

The problem is that the straightforward guess doesn't work:

```
dijkstra_shortest_paths(R,u,
 predecessor_map(get(vertex_predecessor,R))
  .distance_map(get(vertex_distance,R))
   .weight_map(get(edge_weight,R)));
```

The boost doc pages are very frugal about reverse graphs... I managed to narrow it down to an issue with accessing the edges of `R`, I think, since this works:

```
print_graph(R,get(vertex_name,R));
```

but this doesn't:

```
print_graph(R,get(edge_weight,R));
```

Comment: Have you tried `boost::make_reverse_graph(G)`?